# Continued - GLM fit (logistic regression) to SQL

Tags: sql, r, teradata, glm, sqldf

As stated Tomas Greif in:
 [GLM fit (logistic regression) to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28698395/6497137)

## Original Question:

We frequently score data in database directly for simple models like linear or logisitc regression. It is always a little bit tricky to transfer all coefficients from R to SQL correctly. I thought I can make some R to SQL translation for glm result. For numeric variables this is pretty straightforward:

```
library(rpart)

fit <- glm(Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis, family = binomial())

coefs <- fit$coef[2:length(fit$coef)]
expr <- paste0('1/(1 + exp(-(',fit$coef[1], '+', paste0('(', 
           coefs, '*', names(coefs), ')', collapse = '+'),')))')

print(expr)

a <- with(kyphosis, eval(parse(text = expr)))
b <- predict(fit, kyphosis, type = 'response')
names(b) <- NULL
all.equal(a, b)
```

The generated expr is:

```
1/(1 + exp(-(-2.03693352129613+      (0.0109304821420485*Age)+   (0.410601186932733*Number)+(-0.206510049753697*Start)))).
```

Is there a way how to make this work for factor variables? I would like to put factors in case ... when ... then ... end clause. Suppose we have the following model:

```
kyphosis$factor_variable <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],20)[1:81]
fit <- glm(Kyphosis ~ ., data = kyphosis, family = binomial())
```

I am browsing through structure of fit, but do not see anything useful. Is the only option to parse names(fit$coef)?

Here's a reference to the best answer so far...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33659431/6497137

#### Potential Solution

```
glm_to_sql <- function(glmmodel) {
  xlev <- data.frame(unlist(glmmodel$xlevels))
  xlev$xlevrowname <- rownames(xlev)
  rownames(xlev) <- NULL
  colnames(xlev)[1] <- "xlevel"
  if (nrow(xlev)==0){xlev <- data.frame(xlevrowname=character(0), xlevel=character(0), stringsAsFactors=F)}

  modcoeffs <- data.frame(unlist(glmmodel$coefficients))
  modcoeffs$coeffname <- rownames(modcoeffs)
  rownames(modcoeffs) <- NULL
  colnames(modcoeffs)[1] <- "coeffvalue"

  coeffmatrix <- sqldf("select a.*,b.*,'' as sqlstr, 
                       substr(coeffname,1,instr(coeffname, xlevel)-1) as varname 
                       from modcoeffs a left join xlev b on coeffname like '%' || xlevel and xlevrowname like substr(coeffname,1,instr(coeffname, xlevel)-1) || '%'")

  for (i in 1:nrow(coeffmatrix)) {
    if(coeffmatrix$coeffname[i] == "(Intercept)") 
    {
      coeffmatrix$sqlstr[i] <- coeffmatrix$coeffvalue[i]
    } else if (is.na(coeffmatrix$xlevel[i]) ) {    
      coeffmatrix$sqlstr[i] <- paste("(",coeffmatrix$coeffvalue[i],"*",coeffmatrix$coeffname[i],")")
    } else {
      coeffmatrix$sqlstr[i] <- paste("(case when ",coeffmatrix$varname[i],"='",coeffmatrix$xlevel[i], "' THEN ",coeffmatrix$coeffvalue[i]," ELSE 0 END)",sep="")
    }

    if (i==1){x.sql0 <- coeffmatrix$sqlstr[i]} else {x.sql0 <- paste(x.sql0,"+",coeffmatrix$sqlstr[i])}
  }

  if (glmmodel$family$link == "logit") {
    x.sql <- paste("1/(1 + exp(-(",x.sql0,")))")  
  } else if (glmmodel$family$link == "identity") {
    x.sql <- x.sql0
  }

  return(x.sql)
}
```

#### Problem

The sqldf join isn't perfect:

```
where varname is null or length(varname) >0 ## additional filter
```

This doesn't get rid of all the corners. If the variable ends (i.e. Human) in "n" and another variable (i.e. surivor) is y/n then it'll subtract the "n" from human and pair it with all the other y/n variables.

Does anyone have a potential work around solution?

## EDIT: Example

```
library(sqldf)
ID <- seq(1,50,  1)

cabin <- as.numeric(as.character((seq(1,25.5,  .5))))

str(cabin)

Defect <-     c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)

Pre_register <- c("Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y",
             "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y",
             "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", 
             "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "N")

length(Pre_register)
length(cabin)
length(ID)

x <- data.frame(cbind(ID, cabin, Pre_register, Defect))

x$cabin <- as.numeric(as.character(x$cabin))

str(x)

glm_ex <- glm(Defect ~ cabin + Pre_register ,
           data=x,
           family=binomial(link="logit"))

summary(glm_ex)
```

And here's the output:

```
> glm_to_sql(glm_ex)
```

[1] "1/(1 + exp(-( 0.97216 + (case when FLT_REV_Jan_Sep_2015='Y' THEN Round(-1.95327, 3) ELSE 0 END) + **(case when ='N' THEN Round(-1.93112, 3) ELSE 0 END)** )))"

Note the case statement has a blank equals "N". **This piece is wrong** and is a problem with the glm_to_sql logic.

It's the join where cabin ends in "n" is mixed up with Y/N. This is a much smaller example.

#### EDIT2:

Walking through glm_to_sql:

```
xlev <- data.frame(unlist(glm_ex$xlevels))

xlev$xlevrowname <- rownames(xlev)

rownames(xlev) <- NULL

colnames(xlev)[1] <- "xlevel"

if (nrow(xlev)==0){xlev <- data.frame(xlevrowname=character(0), xlevel=character(0), stringsAsFactors=F)}

xlev

modcoeffs <- data.frame(unlist(glm_ex$coefficients))

modcoeffs$coeffname <- rownames(modcoeffs)

rownames(modcoeffs) <- NULL

colnames(modcoeffs)[1] <- "coeffvalue"

modcoeffs
```

Here is where the problem exists:

```
coeffmatrix <- sqldf("select a.*,b.*,'' as sqlstr, 
                   substr(coeffname,1,instr(coeffname, xlevel)-1) as varname 
                 from modcoeffs a left join xlev b on coeffname like '%' || xlevel and xlevrowname like substr(coeffname,1,instr(coeffname, xlevel)-1) || '%'")
```

Output:

```
   coeffvalue     coeffname xlevel   xlevrowname sqlstr      varname
1 -0.51243845   (Intercept)   <NA>          <NA>                <NA>
2 -0.04240967         cabin      N Pre_register1                    
3  1.17625756 Pre_registerY      Y Pre_register2        Pre_register
```

The problem exists on line 2 of the output - cabin gets associated with the Y/N from Pre_register levles of Y/N and cabin ending in the letter n gets made into a level.

Comment: Are you sure your "example corner problem" is actually a problem? How familiar are you with how R handles the coding and estimation of factors levels in glm? I don't see a demonstration that this fails.

Comment: Try running the above example - does this help? I believe this is a "corner" example.

Comment: The code to make that output would be `glm_to_sql(glm_ex)` and you would first need to load the sqldf library. There should be no CASE statement for a numeric variable. The value of a numeric variable should be multiplied by its coefficient. And perhaps most importantly NEVER use the construction  `data.frame(cbind(...))`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Please excuse my poor example trying to mock up some code. I also forgot to include the loading various packages in my example. They were already loaded when I ran this example. 

As you pointed out the case statement shouldn't apply for a numeric variable. That's the problem. I believe this glm_to_sql piece of code needs to be tweaked and I was asking for assistance.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: 42 - Does this explain where is issue exists? I'm trying to demonstrate how this fails.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention you're using Teradata, there's a simple way of doing this, although it may not be applicable to you. Just run the scoring code in R, directly on your server.

```
# fit the logistic regression model (or any other model)
modLR <- glm(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis,
             family=binomial)

connStr <- "insert_ODBC_connection_string_here"

# input and output tables
inTbl <- RxTeradata("input_table_name", connectionString=connStr)
outTbl <- RxTeradata("output_table_name", connectionString=connStr)

# set the compute context to in-DB
ccTD <- RxInTeradata(connectionString=connStr)
rxSetComputeContext(ccTD)

# do the scoring
rxDataStep(inTbl, outTbl,
           transforms=list(
               pred=predict(.modLR, data.frame(Age, Number, Start))
           ),
           transformObjects=list(.modLR=modLR),
           transformPackages="stats")  # or rpart, randomForest, gbm, etc
```

This fits the model on your local desktop/laptop, and then sends it to the R process running on the server. The scoring takes place entirely on the server, with no data movement back to your desktop.

If the model involves factors, this can be handled (relatively) easily by constructing the factor as part of the predict call:

```
rxDataStep(inTbl, outTbl,
           transforms=list(
               pred=predict(.modLR,
                   data.frame(Age, Number=factor(Number, levels=2:10), Start))
           ),
           transformObjects=list(.modLR=modLR))
```

Setting things up so that metadata like factor levels etc are treated correctly is a bit tedious; I've omitted the details but hopefully you can see how it would be done.

**This requires Revolution/Microsoft R Server to be installed on your Teradata box.** Since you're asking this question, I suspect that MRS isn't installed (or you'd be using it already). Nonetheless, I'm putting this here because it may help someone else with Teradata who sees this question.

The same solution works with Microsoft SQL Server as well, naturally. We supported Teradata when Revo was an independent company, and that support isn't going away post-acquisition.

Disclosure: I work for Microsoft.

Comment: That looks like a great solution if we had R installed on our Teradata box but there's no way I'm getting access to it :)    I'm trying to find a solution where I can create some SQL and hand it off to another coworker/group to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Hello another option is that you can build your GLM's with R and generate the equivalent source code with the glm.deploy package, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glm.deploy/index.html
you could generate the GLM code in C or JAVA, and translate it to SQL more easily or build a user defined function for a specific DBMS